# Keras custom loss function with argwhere-like check

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to create a custom loss function in Keras for generator that generates matrix. The matrix consists of higher number of elements and low number of their centers. Centers have high value comparing to elements - elements have value `<0.1`, while centers should reach value `>0.5`. It is important that the centers are at exact correct indices, while it is less important to fit elements. That is why I am trying to create loss that would do the following:

1. select all elements from `y_true` where value is `>0.5`, in numpy I would do `indices = np.argwhere(y_true>0.5)`
2. compare values at the given indices for `y_true` and `y_pred`, something like `loss=(K.square(y_pred[indices]-y_true[indices]))`
3. select all other elements `indices_low = np.argwhere(y_true<0.5)`
4. same as step 2, save i.e. as `loss_low`
5. return weighted loss, i.e. `return loss*100+loss_low`, simply to give higher wight to more important data

However, I cannot find a way to achieve this in keras backend, I have found [a question about `tf.where`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553646/keras-how-to-find-indices-from-a-tensor-for-a-particular-value-similar-to-nump), trying to look for something similar to my problem but there seem to be nothing like `tf.argwhere` (can't find in docs, neither browsing net/SO). So how can I achieve this?

Note that the number and positions of centers can vary, and the generator is bad from start so it will not generate any or will generate way more than really should be, so I think that I can't simply use `tf.where`. I might be incorrect here as I am new to custom loss functions, any thoughts are welcome.

**EDIT**

After all it seems `K.tf.where` was exactly what I was looking for, so I have tried it out:

```
def custom_mse():
    def mse(y_true, y_pred):
        indices = K.tf.where(y_true>0.5)
        loss = K.square(y_true[indices]-y_pred[indices])  
        indices = K.tf.where(y_true<0.5)
        loss_low = K.square(y_true[indices]-y_pred[indices]) 
        return 100*loss+loss_low
    return mse
```

but this keeps throwing an error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3 for 'loss_1/Generator_loss/strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,?,?,?], [1,?,4], [1,?,4], [1].
```

How can I use the `where` output?

Comment: what is the shape of y_true and y_pred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I finally found the correct solution, so it might help somebody in the future:

Firstly my code was biased by my long time work with numpy and Pandas, thus I have expected tf elements can be addressed as `y_true[indices]`, there are actually built in functions `tf.gather` and  `tf.gather_nd` for getting elements of a tensor. However, since number of elements in both losses are different, I can't use this because counting losses together will lead to incorrect size error.

This led me to a different approach, [thanks to this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382175/setting-values-of-a-tensor-at-the-indices-given-by-tf-where). Understanding the code in the accepted answer I have found that you can use `tf.where` not only to get indices, but as well to apply masks to your tensors. The final solution for my problem is then to apply two masks on the input tensor and calculate two losses, one where I count loss for higher values and one where I count loss for lower values, then multiply the loss that should have higher weight.

```
def custom_mse():
    def mse(y_true, y_pred):
        great = K.tf.greater(y_true,0.5)
        loss = K.square(tf.where(great, y_true, tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_true)))-tf.where(great, y_pred, tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred))))
        
        lower = K.tf.less(y_true,0.5)
        loss_low = K.square(tf.where(lower, y_true, tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_true)))-tf.where(lower, y_pred, tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred))))
        return 100*loss+loss_low
    return mse
```